# TestComplete and Adobe Air

Tags: testing, air, automated-tests, testcomplete

Does anyone know if TestComplete can be used with Adobe Air applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Hi, TestComplete 7 does not support Adobe Air natively. The only thing it can does with such applications is black-box coordinate-based testing.</s>

**Update:** Yes, starting from version 8.10 TestComplete fully supports testing AIR applications. [Here](http://www.automatedqa.com/blogs/post/10-12-22/testcomplete-8-10-testing-adobe-air-applications/) is a quick overview.